# Extracting highest value in some unequal periods/time-series

Tags: r, date, dataframe, overlap

I have two data frame: period_example (consists of `Beg`, and `End`) and price_example (consists of `Date` and `High`). I want the highest value of High for each Beg-End period. How to do it? Thank you.

Here is the data:

```
period_example <- data.frame(Beg = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-04","2000-01-09")),
                             End = as.Date(c("2000-01-03","2000-01-08","2000-01-12")))
price_example <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-12"), by="days"), 
                            High = c(100,105,104,103,102,106,107,108,109,110,115,114))
```

The result should be like this:

```
result <- data.frame(Beg = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-04","2000-01-09")),
                     End = as.Date(c("2000-01-03","2000-01-08","2000-01-12")),
                     High = c(105,108,115))
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow :-) this site isn't a code generator, please show what you've tried ([mcve]), and look at [ask]

Comment: ups. Sorry JimHawkins, my mistake didn't read How to Ask before. will do next time.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution for this problem, you could apply a function to each row and find the max between these dates in the other data frame:

```
period_example <- data.frame(Beg = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-04","2000-01-09")),End = as.Date(c("2000-01-03","2000-01-08","2000-01-12")))
price_example <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-12"),by="days"), High = c(100,105,104,103,102,106,107,108,109,110,115,114))

period_example$High <- apply(period_example,1 , function(x) max(price_example[price_example$Date >= x[1] & price_example$Date <= x[2], "High"]))
> period_example
         Beg        End High
1 2000-01-01 2000-01-03  105
2 2000-01-04 2000-01-08  108
3 2000-01-09 2000-01-12  115
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` has a fast function for this: `foverlaps`.

```
library(data.table)

x = setDT(period_example)
y = setDT(price_example)

y[, `:=` (Beg = Date, End = Date)]

setkey(x, Beg, End)
z = foverlaps(y, x)

z[, .(High = max(High)), by = .(Beg, End)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
period_example <- data.frame(Beg = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-04","2000-01-09")),End = as.Date(c("2000-01-03","2000-01-08","2000-01-12")))

price_example <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-12"),by="days"), High = c(100,105,104,103,102,106,107,108,109,110,115,114))


betweenDates <- function(target,beg,end){
  beg <- as.Date(beg)
  end <- as.Date(end)
  target <- as.Date(target)
  return(target>=beg&target<=end)
}

selecteDates <- sapply(price_example$Date,function(x) betweenDates(x,period_example$Beg,period_example$End))


highValues <- sapply(1:nrow(period_example),function(x) max(price_example$High[selecteDates[x,]]))


result <- data.frame(period_example,High=highValues)
```